# c++ - How to use a function in a Struct?

Tags: c++, function, struct

In main, I call a function;

```
int main()
{
    func1(159);
}
```

func1 function declares an object;

```
void func1(int data) {
    struct node* add = newNode(data);
}
```

Here is the struct;

```
    struct node *newNode(int data) {

    func2(... , ...);

    return ...;
}
```

And here is func2;

```
void func2(... , ...)
{
//code here
}
```

Error is " 'func2' is not declared."

Comment: please create a [MCVE] something that we can just copy paste in our compiler.

Comment: Googling "c++ function prototypes" is somewhat likely to help you.

Comment: You have to store either a function pointer, a function object or an instance of `std::function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare func2 before newNode. Forward references are not possible.

possibly, you DID declare func2 before but it had a compile error itself, please check further above in the log.

By the way, newNode is not "the struct". "The struct" is that variable what you have named node and is not declared, which does not matter because you have no reference to its contents.

Comment: Thank you. Just declaring func2 before newNode solved my problem. I have declared node by the way. I just didn't want question to be so long.

Comment: Yes. newNode is a function with a POINTER to a struct as return value.